# Express.js POST req is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to make a POST request to the server to put some data in the database via Express and Sequelize

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    _ = require('lodash');

sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite://' + path.join(__dirname, 'invoices.sqlite'), {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: path.join(__dirname, 'invoices.sqlite')
});

Invoice = sequelize.define('invoices', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  customer_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  discount: {
    type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
  },
  total: {
    type: Sequelize.DECIMAL
  }
});

var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.route('/api/invoices')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    let invoice = Invoice.build(_.pick(req.body, ['customer_id', 'discount', 'total']));
    invoice.save().then(function(invoice){
      res.json(invoice);
    });
  });
```

But, when fetching with a POST request, undefined comes as req. Fetch request body is not null, I've checked it.

Comment: body-parser exists in package.json in devDependencies as well

Comment: Not related with error, but body-parser must be in dependencies not in devDependencies

Comment: How do you test your route? If with postman, can you share a screenshot showing your body?

Comment: It seems like you have incorrect `Content-Type`, you can check it by adding your own middleware like `app.use( function (req, res, next) { console.log('Content-Type: ', req.get('content-type')); next(); });`

Comment: The problem might be in content-type indeed. Console logs content-type undefined. Moreover, I found an error in console TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined, so now I'll try to fix it

Comment: @SuleymanSah I test my route just in console just like this  `.post(function(req, res) {
    let invoice = Invoice.build(_.pick(req.body, ['customer_id', 'discount', 'total']));
    console.log('API req.body is' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    invoice.save().then(function(invoice){
      res.json(invoice);
    });
  });` Console logs `Content-Type:  undefined
API req.body is{}`

Comment: This is fetch request parameters `fetchDatabase request is {"uri":"http://localhost:8000/api/invoices","fetchMethod":"POST","body":{"id":"","customer_id":"1","discount":"2","total":"12"},"id":null,"database":"invoices","treatMethod":"add"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.post('/api/invoices',
      (function(req, res) {
        let invoice = Invoice.build(_.pick(req.body, ['customer_id', 'discount', 'total']));
        invoice.save().then(function(invoice){
          res.json(invoice);
        });
      });
```

don't use route....

Comment: Chances are, I'm doing sth wrong, but this didn't help, Content-type is still undefined and req.body is still an empty object `Content-Type:  undefined
API req.body is{}` `fetchDatabase request is {"uri":"http://localhost:8000/api/invoices","fetchMethod":"POST","body":{"id":"","customer_id":"3","discount":"2","total":"32"},"id":null,"database":"invoices","treatMethod":"add"}`

Comment: I don't use postman. Now I moved middleware declararions before the routing and added a line into app.post `req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';`, Content-type changed to text/plain;charset=UTF-8, req.body is still an empty object

Comment: Well, I tried postman, the problem is, despite I set necessary keys and values in request body, server gets an empty object

Comment: Why should you not use ``app.route``? Just curious. I use it and I don't have any problems.